# PHP - How to pass variable in a text filed with double quote

Tags: php, mysql

My query extract a data value from mysql table where are a double quote in the text.

```
Select mytitle from title_table
```

The result is: This is my title: "for school"

This value I want to put inside a text field, but is truncated in this position **This is my title:**

I print the title by this: `<?php echo $rows['mytitle']; ?>`

How to put the entire title in a text field?

Thanks

Comment: I'm amazed that there are 3 answers for this question and all of them has proposed same answer and none of them has understood the OP's question and all of the answers are wrong!!!

Comment: many have misunderstood definitely. The important thing is that he has found the solution I posted

Answer (score 0):

Print inside the value of the text field, example:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $rows['mytitle']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this problem. Are easy, but in a first time make a wrong Google search.
I have resolve by this: htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

I think you search for this

```
<?php

echo '<input type="text" value="' . $rows['mytitle'] . '">';
?>
```

or in plain HTML with

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$rows['mytitle'];?>">
```

Look to, for the second example you must have enabled short_tags in your php.ini or use

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['mytitle'];?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="yourkey" value="<?php echo $rows['mytitle'] ?>" />
```

Comment: Congratulation and tnx